# Erro de SQL: ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, inner-join, inner

Preciso implemntar este GROUP BY , mas dá erro. Erro de SQL: ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY

Montei este select , mas esta dando erro ORA-00979.Primeiro implementei o inner join deu certo, mas depois eu quis implemtar o GROUP BY para enxugar a tabela usando a função SUM . Objetivo: trazer cd_cnta_cntb e somar o valores da coluna vl_movi_cred e vl_movi_debt e apresentar o total na coluna vl_movi_calc.

```
SELECT
    dcc.sk_cnta_cntb,
    dcc.cd_cnta_cntb,
    flc.sk_data,
    SUM(flc.vl_movi_cred),
    SUM(flc.vl_movi_debt),
    (SUM(flc.vl_movi_cred - flc.vl_movi_debt) *(
        CASE
            WHEN substr(cd_cnta_cntb, 1, 1) IN(
                5, 6, 7
            ) THEN
                - 1
            ELSE
                1
        END
    )) vl_movi_calc
FROM
    irodim.di_dim_cnta_cntb   dcc
    INNER JOIN irodim.fa_dim_lanc_cntb  flc ON ( dcc.sk_cnta_cntb = flc.sk_cnta_cntb )
WHERE
    dcc.cd_cnta_cntb = 946054
    AND flc.sk_data BETWEEN 20180901 AND 20180930
GROUP BY
    dcc.cd_cnta_cntb,
    dcc.sk_cnta_cntb,
    flc.vl_movi_cred
ORDER BY
    dcc.sk_cnta_cntb;
```

Comment: Faltou o flc.sk_data no group by.

Answer (score 0):

Sua cláusula **Group By** está errada.  O Group By tem que conter todos os campos, excetos os campos que fazem parte da função SUM.

Altere para:

```
GROUP BY dcc.sk_cnta_cntb, dcc.cd_cnta_cntb, flc.sk_data
```